# How to show the number of items sold for specific value from SQL column and table

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I have a very little knowledge about SQL.

I would like to show the numbers of package sold from my SQL database for specific table value for different ID (package ID) on CodeIgniter.

When I try to put some coding, it shows the same numbers of package sold for all packages.

Table: payments

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->where('payment_status', 'succeeded');
$this->db->where('item_price', '50000.00');
$succeededpayment = $this->db->get('payments');
```

I want to show only payment_status is succeeded, item_price = 50000 from table (payments) for each different ID (package) but it shows the SAME numbers of package sold for all packages.

The code to show the numbers of package sold:

```
<?php echo $succeededpayment->num_rows(); ?>
```

And here is the result;

[result of the numbers of item sold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHbvN.jpg)

The image above displays 22 package sold (at the top right corner).

Fact: Package 1 has 21 sales and Package 2 has 1 sale.

Quiz controller:

```html
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Quiz_Controller extends Public_Controller {

    /**
     * Constructor 
     */
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        $this->load->model('Payment_model');
        $this->load->model('PackageModel');
        $this->load->model('TestModel');
        $this->add_css_theme('quiz_box.css');
        $this->add_css_theme('set2.css');

    }
    
    public function set_leader_bord_user_name()
    {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['msg'] = 'Invalid Response';
        if($this->input->post('inputValue'))
        {
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['name'] = $this->input->post('inputValue');
            $response['msg'] = 'Thanks ! '.$this->input->post('inputValue');
            $this->session->set_userdata('leader_bord_user_name', $this->input->post('inputValue'));
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    function instruction($quiz_id)
    {
        $quiz_data = $this->TestModel->get_quiz_by_id($quiz_id);
        
        $test_taken = $this->TestModel->get_test_taken($quiz_id,$this->user['id']);

        if($quiz_data->is_registered == 1 && empty($this->user['id']))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Login atau Daftar dulu ya!');
            return redirect(base_url("login"));
        }

        if($quiz_data->is_registered == 1 && ($quiz_data->attempt == $test_taken['count']))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('test_already_given'));
            return redirect(base_url());
        }    

        $leader_bord_user_name = $this->session->leader_bord_user_name;
        
        if(empty($leader_bord_user_name) && empty($this->user['id']))
        {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('user_required')); 
           redirect(base_url(''));
        }

        if(empty($quiz_data))
        {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('invalid_id')); 
           redirect(base_url('404_override'));
        }

        $checkUser = $this->db
        ->where('user_id', $this->user['id'])
        ->where('payment_status', 'succeeded')
        ->where('type', 'PACKAGES')
        ->where('due_date >=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->get('payments')
        ->row();

        if(!$checkUser){
            if($quiz_data->price > 0)
            {
                $quiz_last_paymetn_status = $this->Payment_model->get_quiz_last_paymetn_status($quiz_id);
                if(empty($quiz_last_paymetn_status) && empty($quiz_last_paypal_status))
                {
                    return redirect(base_url("quiz-pay/payment-mode/$quiz_id"));
                }
            }
        }
        
        if($this->session->quiz_session)
        {
            $session_quiz_id = $this->session->quiz_session['quiz_data']['id'];
            return redirect(base_url("test/$session_quiz_id/1"));
        }

        $this->set_title(lang('front_quiz_instruction'), $this->settings->site_name);
        $content_data = array(
            'Page_message'       => lang('front_quiz_instruction'),
            'page_title'         => lang('front_quiz_instruction'),
            'quiz_id'            => $quiz_id,
            'quiz_data'          => $quiz_data,
            'total_participants' => $this->TestModel->get_total_participants($quiz_id, $this->user['id']),
        );

        $data = $this->includes;
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('instruction', $content_data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
    }

    function category($category_slug=NULL, $page_no=NULL)
    {
        $quiz_filter = $this->input->get('most') ? $this->input->get('most') : '';
        $session_quiz_data = array();
        $session_quiz_question_data = array();

        if($this->session->quiz_session)
        {
            $get_quiz_session = $this->session->quiz_session;
            $session_quiz_data = $get_quiz_session['quiz_data'];
            $session_quiz_question_data = $get_quiz_session['quiz_question_data'];
        }
```

and the view:

```html
<?php
$quiz_running = 'no_quiz_start';
$session_quiz_id = NULL;
$this->db->where('payment_status', 'succeeded');
$this->db->where('item_price', '50000.00');
$this->db->where('quiz_id', 1);
//$this->db->where('quiz_id', 116);
$succeededpayment = $this->db->get('payments');

$gradients = array();
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-vue';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-angular';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-react';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-material';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-html';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-laravel';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-react-native';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-nuxtjs';

if($session_quiz_data && $session_quiz_question_data) 
{ 
    $quiz_running = 'quiz_running';
    $session_quiz_id = $session_quiz_data['id'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$session_quiz_id."' class='session_quiz_id'>";        
}

if($quiz_list_data)  
{
    foreach ($quiz_list_data as  $quiz_array) 
    {
        $price = $quiz_array->price > 1 ? '₹ '.$quiz_array->price : ' '.lang('free');
        $start_quiz_link = $quiz_array->price > 1 ? '₹ '.$quiz_array->price : ' '.lang('free');
        $quiz_id = $quiz_array->id;
        $quiz_url = $session_quiz_id == $quiz_id ?  base_url("test/$session_quiz_id/1") : base_url("instruction/$quiz_id");
        $quiz_btn_name = $session_quiz_id == $quiz_id  ?  lang('resume_test') : lang("start_quiz");
        if($quiz_url !=  base_url("test/$session_quiz_id/1") && $quiz_array->price > 1)
        {
            $quiz_url = base_url("quiz-pay/payment-mode/$quiz_id");
            $quiz_btn_name = $quiz_btn_name != lang('resume_test') ? lang('pay_now') : $quiz_btn_name;
        }
        
        if($session_quiz_id == $quiz_id)
        {

            $quiz_running_btn = "";
        }
        else if($quiz_array->price > 1)
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = "";   
        }
        else if($quiz_array->is_registered  == 1)
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = "";   
        }
        else
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = $quiz_running;
        }

        $lang_id = get_language_data_by_language($this->session->userdata('language'));
        $translate_quiz_title = get_translated_column_value($lang_id,'quizes',$quiz_id,'title');
        $quiz_title = $translate_quiz_title ? $translate_quiz_title : $quiz_array->title;
        $quiz_title = strlen($quiz_title) > 40 ? substr($quiz_title,0,40)."..." : $quiz_title;
        $quiz_user_name = $quiz_array->first_name.' '.$quiz_array->last_name;
        $quiz_user_name = strlen($quiz_user_name) > 20 ? substr($quiz_user_name,0,20)."..." : $quiz_user_name;
        
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> 
            <div class="card card-bundle" data-turbolinks="false"> 
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <span class="maskk gradient-defaultt <?php echo xss_clean($gradients[mt_rand(0,7)]); ?>"> </span> 
                    <a href="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_url); ?>" data-url="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_url); ?>" id="quiz_<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>" class="thumb-cover  <?php echo xss_clean($quiz_running_btn); ?> statrt_quiz_btn" data-quiz_id="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="<?php  echo lang('start_quiz');?>"> </a>
                    <div class="details card-dark-shadow"> 
                        <div class="quiz_icons">
                            <div class="icon float-left">
                                
                                                                <?php 
                                    if($quiz_array->price > 0)
                                    {
                                        echo '<span class=\'badge badge-warning text-premium\'><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>&nbsp;' . $quiz_array->price . '</span>';
                                        // $start_or_pay = lang('quiz_pay_now');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<span class=\'badge badge-info\'><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i> Gratis</span>';
                                        // $start_or_pay = lang('start_quiz');
                                    }
                                    ?> 
                                   
                            </div>
                            <!--
                             <a href="/javascript:void(0)" class="icon float-left text-white-im"><i class="fe fe-eye mr-1"></i> 
                                <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->total_view);?></span></a>
                                
                                <a href="/javascript:void(0)" class="icon inline-block ml-3 float-right like-quiz text-white-im">
                                    <?php $like_or_not = (isset($quiz_array->like_id) && !empty($quiz_array->like_id) ? 'text-success' : 'text-muted');?>
                                    <i class="fav_icon fas fa-heart <?php echo xss_clean($like_or_not);?> text-white-im" data-quiz_id="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>"></i> 
                                    <?php $total_like = (!empty($quiz_array->total_like) && $quiz_array->total_like > 0 ? $quiz_array->total_like : "");?>
                                    <span class="value like-quiz-count-<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>"><?php echo xss_clean($total_like);?></span>
                                </a> -->
                                
                                <a href="/" class="icon float-right text-white-im"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down mr-1"></i> 
                                <span class="value"><?php echo $succeededpayment->num_rows(); ?></span></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="framework-logo"> 
                                <p class="quiz_title"> <?php echo xss_clean($quiz_title); ?> </p> 
                                <div class="row quiz_middle_icon">
                                    <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                        <i class="fas fa-book-open"> </i> <br>
                                        <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->number_questions); ?> </span> <br>
                                        Files
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>   <br>
                                        <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($total_like);?></span><br>
                                        Like
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Quizmodel:

```html
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class QuizModel extends CI_Model 
{

    var $table = 'quizes';
    var $column_order = array(null, 'title', 'category_title', 'number_questions', 'duration_min' , NULL);
    var $column_search = array('title', 'category_title','number_questions','duration_min');
    var $order = array('quizes.id' => 'DESC');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query() {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->join('category', 'quizes.category_id = category.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = quizes.user_id', 'left');
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) {
            // if datatable send POST for search
            if ($_POST['search']['value']) {
                // first loop
                if ($i === 0) {
                    // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->group_start();
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                // last loop
                if (count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) {
                    // close bracket
                    $this->db->group_end();
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
        // here order processing
        if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } else if (isset($this->order)) {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order) ]);
        }
    }

    function get_quiz() {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();  
        if ($_POST['length'] != - 1) 
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->select('quizes.*,category_title')
        ->order_by('quizes.id', 'desc')
        ->get();
        return $query->result();
        
    }
    
    function count_filtered() {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    
    public function count_all() {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

Thank you good people for your help.

Comment: Hard to give an exact answer as I don't know your table structure or what your controller/view code looks like. But you probably need to add a `where` clause with the package ID to your existing query. Add the following above or below your current `where` clauses: `$this->db->where('package_id', $packageID);` - but replace `'package_id'` with the package ID column name in the table, and `$packageID` with the variable that contains the package ID you want to get the result for.

Comment: Hi @Marleen, thank you for the answer. I try to add `$this->db->where('quiz_id', 1);` but it seems that it still shows the same numbers of package sold for all packages. Right now, there are two packages with ID (1 and 116). This is the result for the packages: https://prnt.sc/dim1lHCHwhX8 This shows all the package with ID 1

Comment: Could you show the controller method and the view file you're using to render the page?

Comment: I have updated the controller, view and model on my description. Thank you @Marleen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're only getting the result once, for a single quiz with a hardcoded id, and then displaying that same result for all quizzes. You want to execute the query for each quiz separately using a different `quiz_id`.

For that, you need to move this query block ...

```
$this->db->where('payment_status', 'succeeded');
$this->db->where('item_price', '50000.00');
$this->db->where('quiz_id', 1);
//$this->db->where('quiz_id', 116);
$succeededpayment = $this->db->get('payments');
```

... to inside of the foreach loop, so that it is executed for each quiz. And then change `$this->db->where('quiz_id', 1);` to `$this->db->where('quiz_id', $quiz_id);` to get the result for the "current" quiz in the loop.

The view then looks like this:

```
<?php
$quiz_running = 'no_quiz_start';
$session_quiz_id = NULL;

$gradients = array();
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-vue';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-angular';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-react';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-material';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-html';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-laravel';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-react-native';
$gradients[] = 'mask gradient-nuxtjs';

if($session_quiz_data && $session_quiz_question_data) 
{ 
    $quiz_running = 'quiz_running';
    $session_quiz_id = $session_quiz_data['id'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$session_quiz_id."' class='session_quiz_id'>";        
}

if($quiz_list_data)  
{
    foreach ($quiz_list_data as  $quiz_array) 
    {
        $price = $quiz_array->price > 1 ? '₹ '.$quiz_array->price : ' '.lang('free');
        $start_quiz_link = $quiz_array->price > 1 ? '₹ '.$quiz_array->price : ' '.lang('free');
        $quiz_id = $quiz_array->id;
        $quiz_url = $session_quiz_id == $quiz_id ?  base_url("test/$session_quiz_id/1") : base_url("instruction/$quiz_id");
        $quiz_btn_name = $session_quiz_id == $quiz_id  ?  lang('resume_test') : lang("start_quiz");
        if($quiz_url !=  base_url("test/$session_quiz_id/1") && $quiz_array->price > 1)
        {
            $quiz_url = base_url("quiz-pay/payment-mode/$quiz_id");
            $quiz_btn_name = $quiz_btn_name != lang('resume_test') ? lang('pay_now') : $quiz_btn_name;
        }
        
        if($session_quiz_id == $quiz_id)
        {

            $quiz_running_btn = "";
        }
        else if($quiz_array->price > 1)
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = "";   
        }
        else if($quiz_array->is_registered  == 1)
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = "";   
        }
        else
        {
            $quiz_running_btn = $quiz_running;
        }

        $lang_id = get_language_data_by_language($this->session->userdata('language'));
        $translate_quiz_title = get_translated_column_value($lang_id,'quizes',$quiz_id,'title');
        $quiz_title = $translate_quiz_title ? $translate_quiz_title : $quiz_array->title;
        $quiz_title = strlen($quiz_title) > 40 ? substr($quiz_title,0,40)."..." : $quiz_title;
        $quiz_user_name = $quiz_array->first_name.' '.$quiz_array->last_name;
        $quiz_user_name = strlen($quiz_user_name) > 20 ? substr($quiz_user_name,0,20)."..." : $quiz_user_name;

        $this->db->where('payment_status', 'succeeded');
        $this->db->where('item_price', '50000.00');
        $this->db->where('quiz_id', $quiz_id);
        //$this->db->where('quiz_id', 116);
        $succeededpayment = $this->db->get('payments');
        
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> 
            <div class="card card-bundle" data-turbolinks="false"> 
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <span class="maskk gradient-defaultt <?php echo xss_clean($gradients[mt_rand(0,7)]); ?>"> </span> 
                    <a href="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_url); ?>" data-url="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_url); ?>" id="quiz_<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>" class="thumb-cover  <?php echo xss_clean($quiz_running_btn); ?> statrt_quiz_btn" data-quiz_id="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="<?php  echo lang('start_quiz');?>"> </a>
                    <div class="details card-dark-shadow"> 
                        <div class="quiz_icons">
                            <div class="icon float-left">
                                
                                                                <?php 
                                    if($quiz_array->price > 0)
                                    {
                                        echo '<span class=\'badge badge-warning text-premium\'><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>&nbsp;' . $quiz_array->price . '</span>';
                                        // $start_or_pay = lang('quiz_pay_now');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<span class=\'badge badge-info\'><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i> Gratis</span>';
                                        // $start_or_pay = lang('start_quiz');
                                    }
                                    ?> 
                                   
                            </div>
                            <!--
                             <a href="/javascript:void(0)" class="icon float-left text-white-im"><i class="fe fe-eye mr-1"></i> 
                                <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->total_view);?></span></a>
                                
                                <a href="/javascript:void(0)" class="icon inline-block ml-3 float-right like-quiz text-white-im">
                                    <?php $like_or_not = (isset($quiz_array->like_id) && !empty($quiz_array->like_id) ? 'text-success' : 'text-muted');?>
                                    <i class="fav_icon fas fa-heart <?php echo xss_clean($like_or_not);?> text-white-im" data-quiz_id="<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>"></i> 
                                    <?php $total_like = (!empty($quiz_array->total_like) && $quiz_array->total_like > 0 ? $quiz_array->total_like : "");?>
                                    <span class="value like-quiz-count-<?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->id);?>"><?php echo xss_clean($total_like);?></span>
                                </a> -->
                                
                                <a href="/" class="icon float-right text-white-im"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down mr-1"></i> 
                                <span class="value"><?php echo $succeededpayment->num_rows(); ?></span></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="framework-logo"> 
                                <p class="quiz_title"> <?php echo xss_clean($quiz_title); ?> </p> 
                                <div class="row quiz_middle_icon">
                                    <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                        <i class="fas fa-book-open"> </i> <br>
                                        <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($quiz_array->number_questions); ?> </span> <br>
                                        Files
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>   <br>
                                        <span class="value"><?php echo xss_clean($total_like);?></span><br>
                                        Like
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Dear @Marleen, Thank you very much for the help. This is working!